# Intern - Create local tunnel to run functional tests

Tags: unit-testing, functional-testing, intern

So i'm starting use Intern for functional tests, so far so good I did it all, unit and functional tests.

I followed their [intern-tutorial](https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial)

> Whenever you need to run a full test against all platforms, use the test runner. When you are in the process of writing your tests and want to check them for correctness more quickly, you can either use just the Node.js client (for unit tests only) or create an alternate configuration file that **only tests against a single local platform, like your local copy of Chrome** or Firefox (for all tests, including functional tests).

I searched on their documentation, but I didn't find anything exactly about local "tunnels".

I'm using Intern with Gulp, my localhost is localhost:3000 and I want to test on my Chrome 54 on Mac.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to change the tunnel to [Local Selenium](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#local-selenium).

> 1. Download the latest version of ChromeDriver
> 2. Set tunnel to 'NullTunnel'
> 3. Run chromedriver --port=4444 --url-base=wd/hub
> 4. Set your environments capabilities to [ { browserName: 'chrome' } ]
> 5. Run the test runner

Obs:

1. Don't forget to copy the `chromedriver` file to your project root.
2. I had to run on my project root `.\chromedriver --port=4444 --url-base=wd/hub`
3. The test runner has to be run in a new command line/terminal/shell

Hope to help someone that had the same issue.

Comment: Actually, when you use newer version of Intern (>= 3.3.2) and use the tunnel SeleniumLocal, you don't need to do the extra steps as you mentioned above. You can read more info here: https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2016/08/18/intern-3-3-released/

Comment: Thank you, i'll take a look on that

Comment: Sorry, the tunnel SeleniumTunnel, not SeleniumLocal :)

Comment: Ahh i was reading about it and didn't understand what's the difference on local.

Comment: By using SeleniumTunnel, you don't need to do step #1, #3 above

Answer (score 1):

I guess [NullTunnel](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#runner-config) is what you're looking for?

Comment: yes! then i found a solution. It isn't clear on intern-tutorial, how to do it / where to find info about it. I answered my own question here :)